# Sharepoint 2010 Content Editor WebPart and missing Modify Shared Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/10/sharepoint-create-quote-of-day-web-part.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+TechTrainingNotes+%28Mike+Smith%27s+Tech+Training+Notes%29)

When I click on the arrow of CEWP, I don't have Modify Shared WebPart option there. The tutorial says it's for 2007 and 2010 both.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: SharePoint related questions would be very welcome on [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) - you might want to consider posting it there, or better still asking for it to be migrated.